# SSL Websocket can't establish a connection since today

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, networking, websocket

I wish all readers Merry Christmas and nice gifts,
My christmas gift was a connection error with my websocket project.

Backend is a Ubuntu Linux virtual instance with an apache server and python 3.10 with websockets as lib.
Frontend is a Ubuntu Linux virtual instance with an apache server and a builded webgl appliance.

Since today i cant create a connection with the same code.
JS:

```
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://domain:port");
..
```

Python:

```
...
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile="./cert.pem", keyfile="./privkey.pem")


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(server, "", port, ssl=ssl_context):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

The frontend is on a diferent webserver as the websocket server.
I can create a connection with ws. The port is open (i checked it in my cloud overview and over ufw and nmap)
I have ssl certs for my frontend and backend with differenz domains/ips created over lets encrypt and these are valid today.

**ERROR** Message: "firefox can't establish a connection to the server wss://domain:port"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLPM1.png)

Have anybody an idea why this sucks up today ?

What i did:
Restarted my pc
Restarted my cloud pc
Drank a beer
Reseted my code to a date who i know 1oo% that was working
Tested it without ssl

Expected result: connection can created over ssl..

Comment: Show the full details in your question of any error messages you received.

Comment: i got the message: "firefox can't establish a connection to the server " same error with edge.

Comment: You need to update Python 3.12.1, will get you not an error.

Comment: any other options ? To build python 3.12.1 on my linux machine is a nightmare, packages that are missing and some other dependency stuff what i cant fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround but I don't know why my problem occurs today...

Workaround:
Run my Python Server(venv) on the same host from frontend.

Javascript:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:port");
```

Python

```
async with websockets.serve(server, "localhost", port):
```

This solves my issue and I don't need a cert file but i have the load on one server.